# Regex context path in jetty ContextHandler?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-8

I am trying to use jetty context configuration ( configuration placed in $JETTY_HOME/context/ ). I am trying to configure a `ContextHandler` that is responsible for serving static files as the one ine `javadoc.xml`. My configuration files is goes like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.eclipse.org/configure.dtd">

<!--
Configure a custom context for serving javadoc as static resources 
-->

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/*/html</Set>

  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/html/</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>index.html</Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
      <Set name="cacheControl">max-age=3600,public</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

What I want is to be able to server any path like /*/html/ but this does not response to calls like /foo/html.

How can I config the path to server any like /foo/html /bar/html /baz/html ? 
If I set the context path like

```
<Set name="contextPath">/foo/html</Set><!--this one works  -->
<Set name="contextPath">/bar/html</Set> <!-- this one works  -->

<Set name="contextPath">/baz/html</Set> <!-- this one works  -->

<Set name="contextPath">/*/html</Set> <!-- this one does not !  -->
```